# Google maps js not displaying in chrome or opera

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-chrome

I've done a lot of searching for this issue, and found a lot of results but none that seem to help in this case. I setup a google map a while ago and it worked. Then with out me changing anything it stopped working in chrome & opera, but still worked in IE and chrome for android. The other day I replaced it with fresh code and got it working again in all browsers, but now I notice it is no longer working in chrome & opera, but works fine in IE and chrome for android. What the devil is going on?

```
<div id="map-canvas" style="width:100%; height:300px; max-width: 100%;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(<? echo $lat; ?>, <? echo $long; ?>);
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 15,
            center: myLatlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map,
            title: "Hello world"
        });
        //marker.setMap(map);
    }

    function loadScript() {
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.type = "text/javascript";
        script.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY_HERE&sensor=false&callback=initialize";
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    }

    window.onload = loadScript;
</script>
```

I will add that I am using twitter bootstrap 2.x on this project in case that has a bearing.

Comment: Not enough information. Look at the error console and see if there was an error.

Comment: I did that already and there is no error. What further info do you suggest I add?

Answer (score 1):

This was an issue with Cloudflare's Rocket Loader. I'm awaiting a fix from CF.